# Cassandra Deletes giving timeout Exception

Tags: ruby, exception, cassandra, timeout

I am using Cassandra 1.0.8 version. Delete requests from ruby-client as well as cassandra-cli is giving timeout Exceptions always.
The properties of the column family used are

```
[default@sample_ks] show keyspaces;            
Keyspace: sample_ks:
  Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy
  Durable Writes: true
    Options: [replication_factor:1]
  Column Families:
    ColumnFamily: sample_cf
      Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType
      Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
      Columns sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType
      Row cache size / save period in seconds / keys to save : 0.0/0/all
      Row Cache Provider: org.apache.cassandra.cache.ConcurrentLinkedHashCacheProvider
      Key cache size / save period in seconds: 200000.0/14400
      GC grace seconds: 864000
      Compaction min/max thresholds: 4/32
      Read repair chance: 1.0
      Replicate on write: true
      Bloom Filter FP chance: default
      Built indexes: []
      Compaction Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy
```

What is the reason for the TimeOut Exception?? How can they be avoided..??

Comment: How many records are you trying to delete?

Comment: @psanford:  one record .. for example, on cassandra-cli I try the following command... del sample_cf['key1']; , del sample_cf['key2'][3]; For these queries I get the exception..

Comment: @psanford: I just realised that the cassandra is not accepting writes also. The commitlog is not getting updated. What might be the problem??

Comment: Are you able to read data? Make sure that cassandra is actually running and that you can connect to the thrift port. Take a look at the logs and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/data/cassandra/data/sample_ks/sample_cf-tmp-hc-425-Filter.db (Too many open files)". Then for every operation(write, del..) the following exception occurs  "org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files"..."

Comment: And also I had set the following settings in the /etc/security/limits.conf file for open files..                      * soft nofile 32768
* hard nofile 32768
root soft nofile 32768
root hard nofile 32768
Is this not enough??

Comment: You should run "lsof" to see what files are open and whether they are opened by a Cassandra process. I am assuming this is happening on your Cassandra node and you are running a local client?